# How to ask for if I can leave hour early to pick my son

Tags: communication, united-kingdom

My son recently joined Kindergarten and my wife work too but the timing is odd for her whereas my work in flexible I.e. if I start at 7, can finish at 4.

Now due to my son starting school. I have to pick him up by 3 which means I have to leave by 2:30. Is there anything called child friendly or any other thing I can discuss with my manager and it doesn’t affect my work.

Comment: Schools in the UK sometimes have after-school clubs where children are looked after by the school for an extra hour or so in exchange for a fee (this doesn't answer your question but might be worth investigating).

Answer (score 9):

> my work in flexible I.e. if I start at 7, can finish at 4.

Given that your work is flexible (and thus your manager is ok with that) some options you can propose I can think of are:

- Ask to go pick your child and then come back to work, leaving some time later so you can do your daily hours.
- See if you can work remotely after you pick up your son. You can also come a bit earlier to office in addition, so the remote time you have to do is less.
- Ask a family member to pick up your son. You can also take turns with them, or with other people you trust to pick up your son, so you only have to ask permission for some days and not every week day.

A combination of the above would also work if you want to.

Comment: You could also ask to reduce your overall working hours (with corresponding reduction in pay).